# Trying to use aliases on a group by sql in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have this sql code that runs but I am trying to name the columns but I am still getting the f0_ , f1_ columns

```
SELECT     use_date, (use_source), sum(New_Users), sum(new_policies), sum(total_cost), sum(MT_enrollments), sum(cf_quoted_users) 
     FROM ( SELECT     use_date, use_source,  New_Users as New_Users, new_policies as new_policies, total_cost as total_cost, MT_enrollments as MT_enrollments, cf_quoted_users as cf_quoted_users       
         FROM    `spot-pet-production.legacy_exec.legacy_exec_data`) itmenames
group by use_date, use_source, New_Users, new_policies, total_cost, MT_enrollments, cf_quoted_users
order by use_date desc
```

and the result

```
Row use_date    use_source  f0_   f1_   f2_  f3_    f4_
1   2022-04-03    wickfire  null null  null null     3.0
```

any help in what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'd name the columns in the outer query. E.g. `sum(New_Users) as Sum_New_Users`

Comment: @jarlh that worked for me, can you post it as an answer so I can give the point to you, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the columns in the outer query instead. E.g.

```
SELECT     use_date, (use_source), sum(New_Users) as Sum_New_Users, ...
```